# Flutter Integartion testing using Gitlab ci

Tags: android, docker, flutter, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to do integration testing of an app built with flutter. I am using cirrusci/flutter docker image for unit testing. I am unable to find any tutorials for integration testing. can anyone help me? Thanks